# mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file

Tags: c++, mpi

I have problems compiling this code using OpenMPI.Since I am a bit new to the concepts of using OpenMPI, it would be great if someone of you could give me a hint to the mistake here.
Compiling works just fine, but if I run the code I get this message:

```
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
      line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).
```

I am compiling using:

```
mpic++ matmult.cpp -o matmult
```

and running it with:

```
mpirun -n 2 matmult
```

... and here is the used code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define MASTER 0
#define FROM_MASTER 1
#define FROM_WORKER 2

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// allocate space for empty matrix A[row][col]
// access to matrix elements possible with:
// - A[row][col]
// - A[0][row*col]

float **alloc_mat(int row, int col)
{
    float **A1, *A2;

    A1 = (float **)calloc(row, sizeof(float *));        // pointer on rows
    A2 = (float *)calloc(row*col, sizeof(float));    // all matrix elements
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        A1[i] = A2 + i*col;

    return A1;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// random initialisation of matrix with values [0..9]

   void init_mat(float **A, int row, int col)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++)
            A[0][i] = (float)(rand() % 10);
   }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // DEBUG FUNCTION: printout of all matrix elements

   void print_mat(float **A, int row, int col, char *tag)
   {
    int i, j;

    printf("Matrix %s:\n", tag);
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) 
            printf("%6.1f   ", A[i][j]);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    int numtasks;
    int taskid;
    int numworkers;
    int source;
    int dest;
    int mtype;
    int rows;
    int averow, extra, offset;
    double starttime, endtime;
    float **A, **B, **C;    // matrices
    int d1, d2, d3;         // dimensions of matrices
    int i, j, k, rc;            // loop variables


    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf ("Matrix multiplication: C = A x B\n");
        printf ("Usage: %s <NumRowA> <NumColA> <NumColB>\n", argv[0]); 
        return 0;
    }

    if (numtasks < 2 ) {
    printf("Need at least two MPI tasks. Quitting...\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc);
    exit(1);
    }

     /* read user input */
    d1 = atoi(argv[1]);     // rows of A and C  d1
    d2 = atoi(argv[2]);     // cols of A and rows of B  d2
    d3 = atoi(argv[3]);     // cols of B and C d3

    printf("Matrix sizes C[%d][%d] = A[%d][%d] x B[%d][%d]\n", d1, d3, d1, d2, d2, d3);

    /* prepare matrices */
    A = alloc_mat(d1, d2);
    init_mat(A, d1, d2); 
    B = alloc_mat(d2, d3);
    init_mat(B, d2, d3);
    C = alloc_mat(d1, d3);


     /* Code für den Manager */
    if (taskid == MASTER) {
        /*printf("matrix multiplikation withMPI\n");
        printf("initializing arrays ...\n");
            for (i=0; i<d1; i++) 
                for (j=0; j<d2; j++) 
                A[i][j]=i+j;


            for (i=0; i<d2; i++) 
                for (j=0; j<d3; j++) 
                B[i][j]=i*j;*/



             /* Matrizen versenden */
            averow = d1/numworkers;
            extra = d1%numworkers;
            offset = 0;
            mtype = FROM_MASTER;

            starttime=MPI_Wtime();

            for (dest=1;dest<=numworkers;dest++) {
                rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow+1 :averow;
                printf("Sending %drows to task %doffset=%d\n",rows,dest,offset);
                MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT,dest,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT,dest,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&A[offset][0],rows*d2, MPI_DOUBLE,dest,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&B, d2*d3, MPI_DOUBLE,dest,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                offset =offset+rows;
            }

             /* Ergebnisse empfangen */
             mtype = FROM_WORKER;

            for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++) {
                source = i;
                MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT,source,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT,source,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                MPI_Recv(&C[offset][0],rows*d3, 
                MPI_DOUBLE,source,mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                printf("Received results from task %d\n",source);
            }

            endtime=MPI_Wtime();
            printf("\nIt took %fseconds.\n",endtime-starttime);
     }       

    /* Code für die Arbeiter */

    if (taskid > MASTER) {
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;

        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&d1, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&A,rows*d2, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&B, d2*d3, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    /* print user instruction */


    // no initialisation of C, because it gets filled by matmult

    /* serial version of matmult */
        printf("Perform matrix multiplication...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < d3; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < d2; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&d1, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&C,rows*d3, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER,mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

    MPI_Finalize();


    /* test output 
    print_mat(A, d1, d2, "A"); 
    print_mat(B, d2, d3, "B"); 
    print_mat(C, d1, d3, "C"); */

    printf ("\nDone.\n");


    //return 0;
}
```

**Results of running** `mpirun matmult` *(default settings, single process)*:

> mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 77202 on node
>   juliuss-mbp-3 exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could
>   occur:
>
> 1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in the
>      job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
>      for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls
>      "init", then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.
> 2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize". By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call
>      "finalize" prior to exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal
>      termination"
> 3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case,
>      the run-time cannot detect that the abort call was an abnormal
>      termination. Hence, the only error message you will receive is this
>      one. This may have caused other processes in the application to be
>      terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here). You can
>      avoid this message by specifying -quiet on the mpirun command line.

Comment: `mpirun -n 2 matmult` try adding a `p` after the `n` for example: `mpirun -np 2 matmult`

Comment: unfortunately I get the same compilermessage for trying this @JonnyHenly

Comment: does the program actually compile when you run `mpic++ matmult.cpp -o matmult`? Have you tried compiling with `g++`?

Comment: it compiles fine using mpic++. with g++ I get linking problems with OpenMPI.@JonnyHenly

Comment: I know this sounds trivial but make sure your in the same directory as your executable. Also try running `mpirun matmult` (default settings, single process) and see if the error is still present.

Comment: Do any of the `printf` statements get called, meaning does the program output anything before or after the mpi error? If so which one(s)?

Comment: Matrix multiplication: C = A x B
Usage: matmult <NumRowA> <NumColA> <NumColB> two times

Comment: I know the problem, I'll post an answer.

Comment: No problem at all, let me know if there is an error with my answer via my answer's comments section.

Answer (score 0):

#### Secondary Issue (still important):

Your program expects an argument count of 4, *ie. program name + 3 arguments passed in*, from this code:

```
if (argc != 4) {
    printf ("Matrix multiplication: C = A x B\n");
    printf ("Usage: %s <NumRowA> <NumColA> <NumColB>\n", argv[0]); 
    return 0;
}
```

Since this conditional returns 0 without calling the proper `MPI_Abort(...)` or `MPI_Finalize()` then you will receive the mpi error:

> mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 77202 on node juliuss-mbp-3 exiting improperly.

By adding `MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc);` before `return 0` I believe your program will be in the clear.

```
if (argc != 4) {
    printf ("Matrix multiplication: C = A x B\n");
    printf ("Usage: %s <NumRowA> <NumColA> <NumColB>\n", argv[0]);
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Primary Issue:

However we should address the main cause of the issue, which is: you need to pass 3 arguments to your program when you run `mpirun -np 2 matmult` or `mpirun matmult`. Which should be in this format:

`mpirun -np 2 matmult parameter1 parameter2 parameter3`
**or**
`mpirun matmult parameter1 parameter2 parameter3`

From your code the parameters (arguments) should be:

`parameter1 = rows of A and C`
`parameter2 = cols of A and rows of B`
`parameter3 = cols of B and C`

and your run command could look like:

`mpirun -np 2 matmult 2 2 2`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I still get an error :(

Comment: MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 1 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD 
with errorcode 32767.

Comment: Try changing the `MPI_ABORT(...)` to `MPI_Finalize()` and let me know the results.

Comment: It is running now. But still not really working:https://www.dropbox.com/s/1eq9nq9lnuk1s7w/Bildschirmfoto%202014-12-18%20um%2008.23.26.png?dl=0

Comment: The error you are receiving *(Floating point exception: 8)* is from this line: `averow = d1/numworkers;` because `numworkers` is never set, ie: divide-by-zero.

Comment: ok thanks so much for your patience! this is what I get if I initilize it with 2 or 1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkkubzwfg4f5dc8/Bildschirmfoto%202014-12-18%20um%2008.49.31.png?dl=0

Comment: try changing `for (dest=1;dest<=numworkers;dest++)` to `for (dest=0;dest<numworkers;dest++)` and set `numworkers` equal to 2.