# mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, with java

Tags: java, mpi, openmpi

I want to run the two java examples Hello.java and Ring.java from [this website](http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=o2YJR96r3hjFagh9JBsZg-SLLnc&cid=2q_J7R93Zbs&s=&projSelected=false&filterChecked#L0).
I compiled them with

```
 ./configure --enable-mpi-java
```

this line worked without any problem.

then I called this line:

```
mpirun -np 2 Hello.java
```

But I get this error:

mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
      line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       alliance

Executable: Hello.java

the same occured when I call

```
mpirun -np 2 Ring.java
```

Can any one help me to solve problem?

PS: this question is not a duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539807/mpirun-was-unable-to-find-the-specified-executable-file), because my question is in java, but the other in c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ring.java and Hello.java are both source code files, not executables. These would first have to be compiled into `.class` files (probably with `javac`). After that I would imagine the call would be

```
mpirun -np 2 java Hello
```